# JS MongoDB deleteOne() returns "deletedCount": 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Struggling with solving why is this not working:

```
    app.delete('/deleteLast', (req,res)=>{
let newDate= new Date;


  stick.find({Day: deCostruct(newDate).Day})
  .then((data)=>{
    let closest;
    closest=findClosestTime(data);

    sticks.deleteOne({Time: closest })
    .then((respoce)=>{
      res.send(respoce);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err);
    });
    console.log("closest time var: "+closest);
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
  });
```

after sending delete request throughout POSTMAN im receiving:

```
"acknowledged": true,
"deletedCount": 0
```

[DB schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHpMV.png)
[DB values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YqSZ.png)
i tried to delete by _id but it's working same way.

Comment: Looks like you have extra blank spaces in the values stored int he database (and that the UI is alerting to you?).  You should probably correct that. But as-is, what happens if you change the delete predicate to `{Time: "09:59:25 " }`?

Comment: No, i double-checked that :)

Comment: What are the two screenshots from? Either way, the fact that `deletedCount` is `0` suggests that no document in the collection the `delete` was run against had a document that matched the predicates. If you're getting the same output when using other fields, then maybe double check the namespace that the `delete` is running against? Eg what is `sticks` here?

Comment: Sticks is const sticks = client.db("SticksDB").collection("Sticks"); client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 }); By the way, i can get this element through sticks.find()

Comment: Helpful, thanks!  Can you similarly retrieve the document if you use the same predicate that you are trying to delete with?  For example `sticks.find({Time: "09:59:25" })`. In either case, you may wish to increase the number of queries logged (`db.setProfilingLevel(0,-1)`) and take a look to see what specific command the database is receiving.

Comment: i can find document with sticks.find({Time: "09:59:25" }). and db.setProfilingLevel(0,-1)) is not working, im receive "MongoInvalidArgumentError: Profiling level must be one of "off, slow_only, all". Not shure what to do with that :)